# trying to get data from one table into another AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get the data from my show data into an artist.past_shows attribute.  I'm using flask_sqlalchemy. I'm getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'past_shows'
```

I'm not quite sure how to do this.  I'm trying to make the query like this:

```
artist = Artist.query.join(Artist.past_shows).filter(Artist.id==artist_id, Show.artist_id==artist_id)
```

These are my models:

```
class Venue(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'venue'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    address = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    seeking_talent = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    seeking_description = db.Column(db.String())
    genres = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.String))
    website = db.Column(db.String())
    pastshows = db.relationship('Show', backref='pastshows', lazy=True)

class Artist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'artist'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    genres = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.String))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    seeking_venue = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    seeking_description = db.Column(db.String())
    website = db.Column(db.String())
    past_shows = db.relationship('Show', backref='past_shows', lazy=True)

class Show(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'show'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    venue_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('venue.id'), nullable=False)
    artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artist.id'), nullable=False)
    artist_name = db.Column(db.String())
    venue_name = db.Column(db.String())
    venue_image = db.Column(db.String())
    start_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False)
```

How can I get the shows data for the artist_id I'm requesting into artist.past_shows?

Comment: what type of DB are you using?

Comment: Please include the traceback. On a glance the error itself looks like something that could be caused by having `Artist.query.past_shows` or such instead of `Artist.past_shows`.

Comment: i'm using postgresql and I am using Artist.past_shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Change the column definition `Venue.pastshows` as following: `pastshows = db.relationship('Show', back_populates='pastshows', lazy=True, primaryjoin="Show.venue_id==Venue.id")`

2 - Change the column definition `Artist.past_shows` as following: `past_shows = db.relationship('Show', back_populates='past_shows', lazy=True, primaryjoin="Show.artist_id==Artist.id")`

3- Try to make a query like this: `artist = Artist.query.join(Show, Artist.id==Show.artist_id).filter(Artist.id==artist_id, Show.artist_id==artist_id)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by creating a data object and putting the data in it using for loops.